# Process Azure Datalake store file using Azure function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-lake

I am getting files in a particular folder on my Azure Datalake store at regular interval. As soon as file come, I want to process it further using an Azure function. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** With [Multi-Protocol Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-multi-protocol-access) for Azure Data Lake Storage, the storage extension should indeed work and some basic tests do confirm that.

There are open issues [[1](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/2387), [2]](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5400) for official confirmation of support.

---

Though Azure Data Lake Storage (ADLS) Gen2 is built upon Azure Blob Storage, there are a couple of [known issues and differences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-known-issues) which are documented.

Because of these differences, I believe we **can't** use the existing bindings available for Blob storage or Event Grid.

But you could still have a Function, triggered by Timer, for example and use the [ADLS v2 REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/data-lake-storage-gen2) to read/update files.

Also, depending on your use case of course, you might really want to look into the other integrations that ADLS v2 supports, namely - [HDInsight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-use-data-lake-storage-gen2?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json), [Databricks](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/data-sources/azure/azure-datalake-gen2.html), [SQL Data Warehouse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-vnet-service-endpoint-rule-overview?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json#azure-sql-data-warehouse-polybase).

Comment: I implemented a function app to process Azure Storage Blob (Blob Triggered), it worked fine, now I would like to implement same with Azure Datalake storage. Is it possible?

Comment: With multi-protocol access not available for azure data lake storage, I believe that should work and I can confirm that some basic tests do work. But I am unsure of any limitations so far in doing so. Please feel free to share any roadblocks you may have hit in the issues linked in my answer to help improve support.

Comment: with v12 sdk the blob api are now GA for datalake as well
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet