# Azure Blob Trigger Function for Data Lake Gen 2

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2

What i am trying to do?
I have a data lake container. inside HDFS name spaces ex: "container/year/month/day/bunch of files". files will upload on daily bases and folder structure is dynamic based on current date . i need my azure function to trigger when files are uploaded in day directory. and those files will process and dump data to sql server db[c# code]. Only i have problem is triggering my function over dynamic directory. please help me or suggest me on how to approach.

Thanks a million.

Comment: I believe you already got answer [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/2387) and also there is this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55874266/process-azure-datalake-store-file-using-azure-function)

Comment: path must be given when compiled. So it should be a const value or already been set in the environment variable. You can have a look of my answer.

Comment: I am really thankful to your answer and comment @BowmanZhu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use dynamic foldername. Actually, the path of the blobtrigger need to be given when compiled. You should give a const or set it in the environment variable.

So, two ways:

**1, The first way is simply. Just do like this:**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp23
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([BlobTrigger("yourcontainername/{year}/{month}/{day}/{filename}", Connection = "str")]Stream myBlob, string filename, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{filename} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
        }
    }
}
```

**2, Second way, Deploy a timetrigger with your blobtrigger. And put the code that can add the environment variable in it.(This timetrigger triggers once a day.)**

I don't recommend this method, Although it can achieve the "dynamic", but I think your use case does not need this. If you really need this, I will update the code. But in theory the first method is sufficient.

Comment: Hope i'm not late. instead of using variable's for year/month/day/name of the file.  have set the scope to container level in run method it works brilliantly Ex: public static void Run([BlobTrigger("yourcontainername", Connection = "str")]Stream myBlob, string filename, ILogger log).  My use case is to trigger function what ever file dropped in container wrt hdfs name space.  Above answer according to Bowman will also works too.